# ASP.NET MVC Problem sending class objects to JS - empty objects in JS array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a ASP:NET MVC application with controller. We HTTP GET to one method in controller.
Inside of it, we want to create Event objects and send the list with all its properties back to the client (in JS).

It doesn't work because in JS we receive a list of empty objects. See attached screenshot. What are we missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

ASP.NET MVC Controller:

```
public class KalenderController : Controller
{
    public class Event
    {
        public Event(int _id, string _title)
        {
            id = _id;
            title = _title;
        }

        public int id;
        public string title;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        StringValues start = "";
        Request.Query.TryGetValue("start", out start);
        StringValues end = "";
        Request.Query.TryGetValue("end", out end);

        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse(start.ToString().Replace(" ", "+"));
        DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Parse(end.ToString().Replace(" ", "+"));

        List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

        DateTime dt = dtStart;
        while(dt <= dtEnd)
        {
            events.Add(new Event(1, "title"));

            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        }

        return Json(events);
    }
}
```

JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Kalender/GetEvents?start=" + fetchInfo.startStr + "&end=" + fetchInfo.endStr,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.dir(data);
        console.log(data.d);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fehler beim Abrufen des Skripts: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    },
    failure: function (bool) {
        alert("Fehler beim Abrufen des Skripts");
    }
});
```

Result of sending data back to client:
Empty objects in JS array: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi7v7.png

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your controller after your Parse() statements. Has dtStart the correct value or is it 0 (default value because it's a struct)? If you know the format of your date string, I would prefer ParseExact (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0). Btw. you can obtain your query parameters with [FromQuery] as a parameter of GetEvents.

Comment: The datetime was correct already, but thanks for suggesting the [FromQuery] Attribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the public fields into public properties on the Event object

```
public class Event
{
    public Event(int _id, string _title)
    {
        Id = _id;
        Title = _title;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```